# How do you handle Infinity in JSON generated in .NET

Tags: .net, json, infinity

The .NET Json serializer serializes Double.PositiveInfinity and the like to things like Infinity, which aren't valid JSON. I'm now trying to use Json.NET to serialize an object to JSON, but I'd like to wrap it so that values like Infinity get converted to NULL, or the string "Infinity". How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to serialize `Double` values as a custom type which provide information on top of the value.  For example

```
{
  'isInfinity': 'true',
  'isNan': 'false'
  'value': '0' };
```

This can be done pretty easily by using a wrapper type to handle `Double` values

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class DoubleWrapper { 
  [DataMember]
  public bool isInfinity;

  [DataMember]
  public bool isNaN;

  [DataMember]
  public double value;

  public DoubleWrapper(double p) {
    isInfinity = Double.IsInfinity(p);
    isNaN = Double.IsNaN(p);
    value = p;
  }
}
```

Comment: I found another way of doing it, but because I'm new I can't post the answer. Basically you can subclass `JsonConverter`, and add it to the `Converters` in `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: @user1016172 didn't realize you could do that. It does seem like an interesting approach.